# Clear All UILocalNotification from Notification Drawer in iOS9 using ObjectiveC

Tags: uilocalnotification

> In my application i am firing alarm notification, if user ignores that
>   then after user launch application at this time i want to clear all
>   the notification from notification drawer which are fired and not yet
>   seen or tapped.

*How can i achieve this?*

tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

but its cancelling the future local notifications.

Comment: referred: https://developer.sinnerschrader-mobile.com/ios-how-to-remove-a-notification-programmatically-from-ios-notification-center/582/ still not getting the solution

Comment: pass a unique id to every schedule notification and than cancel particular localnotification @suhas patil

Comment: yeah, that nice option, worked some how! @salmancs43: Thanks!!